# socket.io app always refreshes on submit

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I installed socket.io into my app. However, when I press the submit button on my form, the page always refreshes.

I've looked this issue up on Google and StackOverflow, tried several solutions (such as making sure my sockets code is within $(document).ready()... code etc.) but still no dice.

I can briefly see a console.log stating the values of the data I put in my inputs, so that part works.

This is my code:

www

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

 var app = require('../app');
 var debug = require('debug')('Webtech2:server');
 var http = require('http');

 //models
 var Comment = require("../models/comments");


/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
 app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

 var server = http.createServer(app);

//Sockets komen hier
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("postComment", function(data) {

    console.log("Socket.io: server received POST");
    //log data naar console
    console.log("Client data log:"+data);

    //stuur 'data' naar iedereen
    io.sockets.emit("update_comment", data);

    Comment.save(data, function(err,res) {
      console.log(res+" added to DB");
      io.emit('update:', res);
    });
  });
});

//op connection doe dit:
io.on("connected", function(socket) {
  Comment.find().exec(function(err, output) {
    socket.emit('show_data', output);
    console.log("Output: "+output);
  });
})

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

 server.listen(port);
 server.on('error', onError);
 server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

 function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

 function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
  ? 'Pipe ' + port
  : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
    console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
    console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    default:
    throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

 function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
  ? 'pipe ' + addr
  : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

public/javascripts/sockets_comments.js (custom name)

```
//jquery voor sockets -- socket.io documentation/
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("socket init ok");

    var socket = io();
    var result = "";

    //data ophalen en naar mongod
    $("#commentSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
        var commentAuthor = $("#commentName").val();
        var commentBody = $("#commentBody").val();
        var commentDate = new Date();

        //log van form data
        console.log("Data opgehaald met waarde: "+commentAuthor+" als author, "+commentBody+" als bodyText en "+commentDate+" als tijdstip.");

        //naar mongo
        result = {
            "cmt_author": commentAuthor,
            "cmt_body": commentBody,
            "cmt_date": commentDate
        }.save;

        //socket connect naar localhost op 3000 en post 
        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
        socket.emit("postComment", result);
        console.log("Verzonden: "+result);

        //reset inputs na send
        $("#commentForm").val("");
    });

    //render
    socket.on("updateComment", function(data) {
        ///
        console.log("Data: "+data);
    });

    //loop visual data
    socket.on("showData", function(output) {
        //loop
        for(var comments = 0; comments < output.length; comments++)
        {
            ////
        }
    });
});
```

Relevant Jade view file

```
extends layout

block content
    header
        div.wrapper
            a(href='/')
              img(src="", alt="Logo")
            a.hvr-grow(href="/discussions") All threads
            span(style="color: white;") &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
            a.hvr-grow(href="/discussions/create") Start a new thread

    div.pageContainer
        h1 #{discussion.title}
        span(id="categoryMarker" class="markers" style="font-size: 1.25em;") &#34;#{discussion.category}&#34;
         span &nbsp;
         a.hvr-grow(href="/discussions" style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;") Back to all threads
        h3 Started by #{discussion.author}
            | &nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
            span Created on #{discussion.date.toDateString()}
            span(style="display: none;") &nbsp;-&nbsp;#{discussion.location}
            br
            br
            div#bodyText
                p #{discussion.body}
    div#commentsSection.pageContainer
        form(action="" name="inputComment" id="commentForm")
            input(id="commentName", placeholder="Your name" name="commentName" required)
            br
            br
            input(id="commentBody", placeholder="Your comment" name="commentBody" required)
            br
            br
            button(class="hvr-grow" type="submit" id="commentSubmit" style="color: black;") Post comment
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/sockets_comments.js")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the `click` handler:

```
$("#commentSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var commentAuthor = $("#commentName").val();
    //...
});
```

By the way, you don't have to connect to socket.io server on each click. You should connect only once as you did it with `var socket = io();`, so you may delete this line:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

**Edit:** As @lxe noticed, it would be actually better to listen `submit` event of the form since it would allow you to intercept pressing `Enter` key as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should listen to `$("#commentForm").on("submit")` instead of `$("#commentSubmit").on("click")`:

```
$("#commentForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  var commentAuthor = $("#commentName").val();
  // ...
  return false; // don't forget to cancel the event too
});
```

EDIT: Here's a generic jsFiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhj6Ltjs/

You can either click the button, or hit Enter (which is the beauty of the `submit` event).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I changed the code as per your example but now nothing happens when I click the submit button, no console.log in browser OR node CMD screen.